# Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, gradle

estoy teniendo este problema, desde que traté de implementar la librería react-native-camera y ejecutar mi proyecto, ya añadí los permisos requeridos en la carpeta android.

```
> Task :react-native-camera:compileGeneralDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :app:mergeDexDebug FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
252 actionable tasks: 33 executed, 219 up-to-date
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\joans\Desktop\Project\new_project\node_modules\react-native-camera\android\src\main\java\com\google\android\cameraview\Camera2.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
D8: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 65711 > 65536 ; # fields: 71075 > 65536)
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
        
.....

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
     The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
     Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
```

Por favor, cualquier sugerencia sería de gran ayuda